# Why don't my ceiling fans work after turning of the breaker?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, ceiling, ceiling-fan

I was replacing a fan in a spare bedroom. Turned off the breaker to that room and quickly figured out through being shocked that the ceiling fan is on a different breaker. So, I turned off the entire breaker box to finish the install. Now, none of my ceiling fans upstairs are working. Help!

Comment: A quality non-contact voltage tester is your friend [Klein NCVT-1](https://amzn.to/437WCaD).

Comment: Will need to test the breaker/s if they are passing current though to the wires.  If that is okay then look for a loose connection.  There is a possibility that the short/shock damaged the fans electronics.  You will need a voltage tester or multi meter.

Comment: I do not believe I have any GFCI in those areas…only kitchen and bathrooms. Yes, a voltage tester is on order!

Comment: How do you test the breakers? Or is it time to call an electrician? Thank you for your help! I know I’m lucky that I didn’t die!

Comment: depending on the type of breakers, some need FIRST to be pushed in OFF position, then in the ON position

Comment: Ok, so apparently there was a GFCI in the garage! I went in the garage to make sure the deep freezer was getting power and it wasn’t. So, I reset the GCFI and lo and behold, that was the issue! Problem solved. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Big lesson, and we all learnt it: Always check for power even if you are sure you got the right breaker...

Comment: @JillMahoney You may want to consider putting the freezer in the garage on a different circuit, as it's counter-intuitive to have a GFCI in the garage control in-house circuits. Garage outlets should always be GFCI protected, _(it's usually code, and if not, simply common sense/good practice)_ and usually there's at least one dedicated circuit that feeds the garage _(sometimes it may have in-house lighting on it for a room closest to the garage, and/or the exterior porch lights as well)_. There are a few ways to do so depending on what branch circuits are in the GFCI electrical box.

Comment: Jill, please take the [tour] to learn how to respond to answers.

Answer (score 3):

Check to make sure there are no GFCI outlets that have tripped and need to be reset. They can be anywhere and can control different appliances throughout the house.

Comment: You don't need evidence for your motives. It's clutter.